# Python Tkinter Withdraw

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmessagebox
from tkinter import *

def Top_Withdraw(top):
    top.withdraw()
    Reaction()

def Reaction():
    top2 = Tk()
    B0 = Label(top2, text = "LOGGED IN", fg = "green", bg = "black", bd = 8)
    B0.pack()
    B1 = tkinter.Button(top2, text = "Character Creator")
    B1.pack(side = LEFT)
    B2 = tkinter.Button(top2, text = "Saved Characters")
    B2.pack(side = RIGHT)


def Reaction2():
    A7 = Label(top, text = "Password saved.")
    A7.pack(side = BOTTOM)

def Character_Creator():
    top3 = Tk()
    C0 = Label(top3, text = "CHARACTER CREATOR", bd = 8)
    C0.pack()



def Login(top):
    A0 = Label(top, text = "WELCOME TO HORSEGARN", fg = "red", bd = 8)
    A0.pack(side = TOP)
    A1 = Label(top, text = "Username")
    A1.pack()
    A2 = Entry(top, bd = 3)
    A2.pack()
    A3 = Label(top, text = "Password")
    A3.pack()
    A4 = Entry(top, show = "*", bd = 3)
    A4.pack()
    A5 = tkinter.Button(top, text = "Log In", command = Top_Withdraw(top))
    A5.pack() 
    var = IntVar()
    A6 = tkinter.Checkbutton(top, text = "Remember password", variable = var, command = Reaction2)
    A6.pack()


top = Tk()
Login(top)
```

Using this code I am trying to minimise the window defined as "top" when the button defined as "A5" is clicked using the "top.withdraw" command. However when I try to run the program, for some reason it does not start at the function Login(top), but instead at Reaction().

Looking at it logically shouldn't the program start at Login(top) and only move to Reaction() WHEN and only when the button defined as A5 is clicked? I cannot see for the life of me why it is hopping instantly to Reaction().

I have tried to define "top" within Login(), within Reaction(), and as a global variable as well but none of this works. Should I not use withdraw?

Answer (score 1):

There are few additional errors in your code. However corresponding to the problem you are talking about there are two main issues.

The following line actually runs the command because you are passing it parameters. Tkinter expects command arguments to be instances, not calls. So here you are passing it a call so it runs that call. Which is why it runs that Top_Withdraw method:

```
A5 = tkinter.Button(top, text = "Log In", command = Top_Withdraw(top))
```

To fix this, use lambda. If you ever have to pass arguments to a button method then you will have to use lambda like so:

```
A5 = tkinter.Button(top, text = "Log In", command = lambda: Top_Withdraw(top))
```

In addition your program will never run because you never put your root window into a mainloop. So be sure to add this on the final line:

```
top.mainloop()
```

This will get your program up and running and make it "disappear" when you hit the login button as you've requested. However I would definitely consider changing a few things such as your imports. You actually import tkinter 3 times all under different ways and then end up calling them different ways in your method. Also you might want to consider putting all of this inside of a class. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Tkinter expects `command` keyword arguments to be something callable, so usually the value provided is a function name or an anonymous one specified with a lambda expression, but it could also be an instance of any callable object.